# How to skip the header line in a text file and read back the rest of the data to the main function?

Tags: c++

I'm just learning about **text file input/output**. I have outputted a file which contains a header and 10 rows of data underneath it.
I now want to read this back to the main function. This works for me if I leave out the header in the text file, but if I leave the header in, I get an infinite loop.
**How can I skip the 1st line (the header line) in reading this data back, or if possible, read back the header as well as the data?**
Here is what I have so far:

```
void fileRead(int x2[], double y2[], int& n, char filename)
{
     ifstream fin ("pendulum.txt"); // fin is an input file stream

     if(!fin) //same as fin.fail()
     {
              cerr << "Failure to open pendulum.txt for input" << endl;
              exit(1);
     }

     int j = 0, dummy = 0; //index of the first value j and dummy  value
     while(!fin.eof()) //loop while not end of file
     {
           fin >> dummy >> x2[j] >> y2[j];
           cout << setw(5) << fixed << j
                << setw(12) << scientific << x2[j] << "   "
                << setw(12) << y2[j] << endl; //print a copy on screen
           j += 1;           
     }

     fin.close(); //close the input file

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first read the header of the file then the real contents you want as follows:

```
string line;
getline(fin, line);//just skip the line contents if you do not want header
while (fin >> dummy >> x2[j] >> y2[j] )
{   //^^if you do not always have a dummy at the beginning of line
    //you can remove dummy when you read the rest of the file
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use

```
    fin.ignore(10000,'\n');
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/
This will ignore the first 10000 character in the file, or ignore the characters until a newline is reached. The 10000 is fairly arbitrary and should be a number that will always be longer than the maximum line length.

Answer (score 0):

man, this gentleman over there helped me quite a lot. You see, everyone says to use getline(); to skip one line, but the problem is that sometimes you dont want to store anything in a buffer, so ignore() makes much more sense to me. Well so I would like to back up our fella's answer by adding that, you could use " numeric_limits::max()" which will make it have no limit, it will ignore until it finds the delimiter...

`

```
  #include <iostream> 
  #include <fstream>
  #include <limits>

  using std::streamsize;

  int main() {
      ifstream fin ("pendulum.txt");
      fin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  }
```

`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/